# boost shared_memory_object use of deleted function

Tags: function, memory, boost, shared

use of deleted function in class operator=

old version worked with old compiler but not with new versions
I need this "operator=" overloading for container operation.

```
#include <boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace boost::interprocess;
class X {
    public:
    size_t m_len;
    shared_memory_object m_shm;
    const char* m_ptr;
    X():
        m_len(0),
        m_shm(shared_memory_object()),
        m_ptr(nullptr){}
    X(size_t t, const char* n):
       m_len(t),
       m_shm(shared_memory_object()),
       m_ptr(nullptr){
       shared_memory_object::remove(n);
       m_shm = shared_memory_object(open_or_create,n, read_write);
       m_shm.truncate (m_len);
       mapped_region region(m_shm, read_write);
       m_ptr = static_cast<char*>(region.get_address());
   }
   X(const X&&  x){
      m_len   = x.m_len;
      m_shm   = x.m_shm; //error use deleted function
      m_ptr   = x.m_ptr;
   }
   virtual ~X(){}    
   X& operator = (const X&& a) {
      if(&a == this)  return *this;
      m_len   = a.m_len;
      m_ptr   = a.m_ptr;
      m_shm   = a.m_shm;  //error use deleted function
      return (*this);
  }
  const char* get_name(){
     return m_shm.get_name();
  }
};
int main ()
{
    X a = X(22, "test");
    X b = a; //Error
   return 0;
};
```

The above class will be used in std::vector and operator= is needed.
boost shared_memory_object has member:

```
shared_memory_object(shared_memory_object &&);
shared_memory_object& operator=(shared_memory_object &&);
```

Comment: What is your error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move operations can only work on non-const objects. Why? Because it *steals* resources from the source instance, then it must be *non-const* to be modifiable. So your move operations should take *non-const* objects:

```
now                                should be
---------------------------------------------------------- 
X(const X&&  x)                ==> X(X&& x)
X& operator = (const X&& a) {  ==> X& operator = (X&& a) {
```

Named variable is treated as L-value, it implies copy operations are called. You need to use `std::move` to cast source to R-value reference, then move operations can be called:

```
      m_shm   = std::move(x.m_shm); // in move ctor 
      m_shm   = std::move(a.m_shm); // in move assignment operator
```

and finally to call move ctor:

```
    X b = std::move(a);
```